# widgets for my web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to create widgets of my web app. The widgets are like textbox with buttons, but that should be enable with drap and drop and resizable feature. The data entered in the widget will be stored in the database. How can I do with the Java script. I am trying to figure it out.

Please do let me know.

Is it safe to use Third party libraries for a enterprise application.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular libraries for creating widgets is jquery UI. I use it in most of my web applications and have had a lot of success with it, and it is found in a lot of enterprise applications. You can learn about it at http://jqueryui.com

Answer (score 0):

just to be a bit more specific than @regality,

jQuery UI is def the way to go, I've used it in a couple of projects now, the bit to look for is the [UI Portlets](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets)

Alternatively, if your after BBC homepage style, take a look at the [BBC's Glow Library](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/).

I recommend using the jQuery Portlets tho...